# Reading directly from the Doctrine Searchable index table

Tags: database, search, doctrine, indexing, tag-cloud

I've got a Doctrine table with the Searchable behavior enabled.

Whenever a record is created, an index is made in another table. I have a model called `Entry` and the behavior automatically created the table `entry_index`.

My question now is: How can I - without using the `search(...)` methods of my model use the data from this table?

I want to create a tag cloud of the words most used, and the data in the index table is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine generates table `EntryIndex` that should be available from `Doctrine::getTable('EntryIndex')`.

Additionally `Entry` has `EntryIndex` relation that refers to index table and `EntryIndex` has `Entry` relation. The relation is standard one-to-many (1-n) relation between `Entry` and `EntryIndex`.

Comment: No EntryIndex is generated. The Searchable implementation uses raw sql as far as I can see.